# Why does the origin observable emits values, if an observable returned by an operator gets subscribed?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe, reactivex

A cold observable needs to be subscribed that it emits values.
When using an operator such as map a new observable gets returned.

```
const origin$ = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4]);
const mapped$ = origin$.map(val => val+1);
mapped$.subscribe(console.log);
```

With `.subscribe` the `mapped$` observable the values get emitted and get logged in the console.

But in this case the `mapped$` observable got subscribed and not the `origin$` observable. Why does the `origin$` observable starts to emit values?

Comment: that's not what hot and cold means in Observable. https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339 and https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html

Comment: @FanCheung Thank you for clarifying my understanding of hot and cold observables. I corrected the question, but I still have this problem in understanding the subscribing mechanism.

Comment: Because you have a chain of observables, that's one of the powers of rxjs Observables, there lazy too, so will only emit when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any operator(oldfashioned with `.map()` or nowadays with `.pipe(map())`) does not return a subscription. Instead it returns a **new** observable which takes the other observable as a source but waits with any subscription until it has a subscription.